# Authentication using bearer token in MVC Web App using C#

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, owin, restsharp

I have developed an OWIN based Web api which generates bearer token. Now in MVC Web application iam using Restsharp to get bearer token. I want to use that bearer token like forms authentication so that i can use **[Authorize]** attribute on action result. Please guide me.

I build the same app for my mobile using HTML, Angularjs and Cordova. Everything is good so far. Now i want to achieve it using c# and MVC5 without using jquery or Angularjs.

A team of 6 people are woking on this application.